# Consulta SELECT*FROM No trae todos los datos

Tags: excel, vba, select, sql

Estoy haciendo una consulta de un archivo de excel a otro. A través de un `recordset` con el metodo `SELECT` traigo las columnas que deseo a mi base, el problema es que tengo una columna `Date de Facture` con datos tipo **FECHA (04/01/2018)** y otros datos tipo **TEXTO (04-AUG-2018)**. Cuando corro la consulta solo me trae los datos tipo FECHA. 
Como hago para que me traiga todos los datos de esa columna y si es posible los traiga todos formato FECHA???

Adjunto el codigo, gracias por la ayuda!

```
Sub Importer_Donnees()
Dim oConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset

Extension = "Tous les fichiers (*.*),*.*"
Index = 5
Titre = "Sélectionnez le fichier à importer ?"
Fichier = Application.GetOpenFilename(Extension, Index, Titre)

If Fichier = False Then
    MsgBox "Aucun fichier sélectionné !": End
Else

Range("BaseFacturation").Clear
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Fichier
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Extraction_Facturation"
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End If

a1 = "Type"
a2 = "N° de Facture"
a3 = "Date de Facture"
a4 = "Transporteur"
a5 = "Ensemble"
a6 = "Mode de tarification"
Ruta = Fichier

oConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & Ruta & "';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';"
oConn.Open ConnectionString:=oConn

rst.Open "SELECT [" & a1 & "],[" & a2 & "], [" & a3 & "],[" & a4 & "],[" & a5 & "],[" & a6 & "] FROM [Extraction_Facturation$A1:BU] ", oConn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

last1 = Sheets("BaseFacturation").Cells(Sheets("BaseFacturation").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

Sheets("BaseFacturation").Range("A" & last1).CopyFromRecordset rst

rst.Close

Last = Sheets("BaseFacturation").Cells(Sheets("BaseFacturation").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

oConn.Close

Sheets("BaseFacturation").Range("A" & Last & ":U1048576").EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Si quieres traer todos los campos porque no haces select * from...

Comment: No conozco el comportamiento interior del parser que estás usando, pero usualmente al parsear la celda hay un valor procesado (por ejemplo el resultado de una fórmula) y un valor "en bruto", como por ejemplo la definición de la fórmula. Otros parsers tienen además un valor con estilos incluyendo el formato de celda. Podrías verificar además si las columnas tienen el mismo comportamiento: un nombre bonito y otro sanitizado en snakeCase, aunque ésto pareciera no tener probemas

Comment: Podrías probar a, una vez hecho `CopyFromRecordset`, convierte todos los datos a Fecha con una macro.